# How to set Djangos through_field to an Intermediate model nested field

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, relational-database

Is there any way I can set [through_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) to an intermediatory models's nested field,

Just for an example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('assignee__group', 'person'),
    )

class GroupLeader(models.Model)
      identity = models.ForeignKey(Person)
      group = models.ForeignKey(Group)  
      #more fields

class Membership(models.Model):
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(GroupLeader)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # more fields
```

I tried doing it but I am getting an error:

```
The intermediary model 'Membership' has no field 'assignee__group'
```

**NOTE: The above is just an example, just in case such a situation is encountered.**

Answer (score 2):

Your group leader should NOT be part of the M2M relation, this is just a `metadata`. So just add `group` into the `Membership` class.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
    )

class GroupLeaders(models.Model)
      identity = models.ForeignKey(Person)
      group = models.ForeignKey(Group)


class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(GroupLeaders)
```

or you can even completely strip out the `GroupLeaders` class

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="leading_memberships",
    )
```

Comment: Suppose my groupleader model hold some more information so that it would not be wise to combine it in membership. Do I really have to add group to membership which groupleader already holds?

Comment: Yes you need a group field in the membership, this is a person-group relations, no matter who the leader is, its your responsibility to assert that the `assignee` is a leader of the same group. Imagine a person stop being a leader of his group, or change his group, should this alter the memberships of everyone from this group?